# Strange DNS issue - can't think of a solution

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, internal-dns

I have a DNS issue that I cant resolve.  My internal windows domain is (e.g.) foobar.uk.net and I used to host a site internally on www.foobar.uk.net.  External DNS records we set to send web requests to my WAN ip which I forwarded - no problems and my internal clients could also browse to the site.

I have recently had a web company redesign and host my site and I have changed my external DNS records to point to the IP address for the web hosting company and all works great but the problem I am getting is that my internal users cant browse to the new site hosted externally.

I'm guessing that it's because the new site is using the same domain name and my internal domain?

I have altered the 'hosts' file on my PC and it does fix the problem but I dont want to have to do this on all 100 client PCs.

I guess I need to create a new record on my internal windows DNS server but I dont know what type of record to create and how I should set it up.

I hope I have explained clearly?  Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks in advance,

James

Comment: Sorted issue - created 2 Host A records.  1 with www in the host name and 1 with nothing in the host name.  Pointed them to the external IP and now all is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows DNS on your server you should be able to create a "www" A record with the appropriate IP address of your new provider.  This is what's called split DNS and is very common.

Comment: I did search google on creating a www record but got no joy.  Where in the DNS folder structure can I create this record?  FYI i'm running windows server 2008R2.

Comment: If you're using IPv4 (you almost certainly are) you'll need to add an A record in to your domain called "www" with the external IP address, this will sit beside entries like your server. E.G. if your internal domain is example.com, and your Domain Controller is DC1.example.com, navigate to the folder containing the DC1 A record, right click on that folder and select "create new A record" then, in the hostname, type "www" rather than "DC1".

Answer (score 0):

For the record, [there are actually **two** ways to do this](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/dns-split-horizon-common-server-names.html).  The second is useful in the case of a hosting company providing the content HTTP service.